# I want a word like "Assure" but on the other way around

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

When someone says: **Prepare *(by wearing nice clothes)* for tonight's date.** Over and over again, whenever that person sees you, he tells you that, not to annoy, harras, or bully you, but to make sure that you understand how important is your preparation for that special night.

So, we say: He ______ to get prepared for tonight's date.

I thought of:

***He "assured me" to get prepared for tonight's date.***

And

***He "made sure/confirmed" that I get prepared for tonight's date.***

But I found that their meanings are ***reassure*** which is like the other way around of the word I want.

The text I have that needs that word (and some correction in its construction, I think) is:

> I'm not sure of how Nathan would react to my preparations. He ______
>   that I get prepared for our only and last night.

That sentence is what a girl says about Nathan, her husband, with a neutral tone, after she didn't have the time to get prepared as she was being told.

Comment: What kind of tone would you like to express?

Comment: If Nathan *succeeded* in his efforts (i.e. - if you *were* prepared), you could just say *He **ensured** [that] I was prepared for tonight's date.* If he failed (you *weren't* properly prepared), but you still want to convey that he did try hard, you could include an idiomatic little construction: *He [was at pains to ensure](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+at+pains+to+ensure%22) [that] I was properly prepared - but I'm not ready, so I feel I've let him down.*

Comment: But to be honest I think there's something not quite right about the required *meaning* here. If Nathan *ensured* something, that means *he made sure it would happen*. Which doesn't make much sense in your cited context, where apparently the *speaker* has made preparations of his own (which Nathan doesn't even know about, so I don't see how we can talk about Nathan making sure of *anything*, if he doesn't know exactly what's happening). All you can say is that he *wanted* you to be ready, or he *tried hard to make you* get ready.

Comment: Every time I saw him he would reiterate that I should prepare for tonight's date.

Comment: @mathewb A worrying tone. Because she can't expect what his reaction would be as she didn't prepare despite his repeating that she has to be prepared when he comes back from work (for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You would have made things easier on both of us, if you had written your comments in the answer's section. Nathan didn't succeded in making her getting prepared as she didn't have time for that. So, when he comes back from work, he would find her unprepared. So, she is worrying that she can't think of what his reaction would be when he sees her. But here's the case, **ensured** is not the word that can fit properly in her sentence, if it means _confirming that something WILL happen_, when it actually didn't.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking here when you say "over and over".  Are you saying that this person is repeatedly telling you to prepare, that he is **nagging** or **pestering** or **hectoring** or **hounding** you?  Or that he is actually undermining your confidence by constantly telling you to be prepared?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo He is repeating it because her preparation is an important thing for him, not because the preparation itself, but because that night is special for him, so he wants her to be prepared for it. And, he repeating that to make sure that she understands how important her preparation is for that night. (repeating something over and over again is annoying in general, but he is not bullying nor harassing her by doing that.)

Comment: @TasneemZh That last comment is helpful. It would help to consolidate the information into your question - in the first sentence, the subject is worried, but that doesn't play into the main word/phrase that you're looking for. That's more neutral. I had considered nagging, at first, as well, but it doesn't sound like that fits what you're describing.

Comment: I updated the question to contain more details. I will try my best to reconsider that next time.

Comment: And what do you mean by  **prepare**?  Get mentally prepared? Gird yourself to meet his boss? Get excited?  Choose the proper attire?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I added the explanation to the question. I intended for **prepare** to mean **"wearing nice clothes"**. Sorry if that wasn't obvious, but getting prepared for a date, commonly means wearing suitable clothes and putting makeup (for women).

Comment: What do you mean by **our only and last night**? As you've described it, the couple are married.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo They are a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the statement is made with a "neutral" tone, by which I take you to mean that there's no criticism of Nathan's behavior here. You write "as she was being told" so it seems you might want a verb like **demanded** or **made clear** or **expects**.

> Nathan demanded that I be ready for the date. I'm not sure how he will react when he finds out that I won't be ready.

or

> Nathan made it very clear that he wanted me to be ready for the date. I'm not sure how he will react when he finds out that I won't be ready.

or

> Nathan said multiple times that he expects me to be ready for the date. I'm not sure how he will react when he finds out that I won't be ready.

Answer (score 2):

This is a phrasal verb, not a single word, but it sounds like [keep on](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/keep+on) may fit the bill. It can be used in different ways, but a simple definition is: `to continue or persist.` A couple of options, depending on what you would like to emphasize would be:

> I *wasn't* sure of how Nathan would react to my *(lack of)* preparations. He had kept on insisting that I get prepared for our *last and only* night.

or:

> ... He had kept on about my preparing for our *last and only* night.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "ensured."

Assure is more passive: telling someone that something will happen without intervention. It's more like a promise.

Ensure is active: making something happen through some enforcing action, such as reminders to prevent someone from forgetting.

> I'm not sure of how Nathan would react to my preparations. He **ensured** that I get prepared for our only and last night.

Comment: How would you say that *ensure* differs from *made sure*, other than word count?

Comment: Nothing really, other than the present tense conjugation *ensure* is equivalent to *make sure*, while past tense *ensured* is equivalent to *made sure.*

Comment: @matthewb I would say that "make sure" is less formal and more colloquial than "ensure" is, as well.

Comment: Despite my having suggested ***ensure*** in a comment, it seems pretty obvious from OP's subsequent comments that Nathan *failed* to ensure his desired outcome, so it can't be the right answer.